# Nodejs: group an array by key for the same values

Tags: node.js

I'm fetching movie lists by `id` and grouping them by name and status.

```
const getListMovie = async(req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id
    if (id) {
        const movie = await Movie.findAll({
            where: {
                id
            },
            attributes: ['status','name', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'total']],
            group: ['name','status']
        });
        console.log(movie);
    }
}
```

**Result :**

```
    {
       "status": 0,
       "name": "x-movie",
       "total": 33
    },
    {
      "status": 1,
      "name": "x-movie",
      "total": 2
    },
    {
      "status": 0,
      "name": "series",
      "total": 1
    },
    {
      "status": 1,
      "name": "series",
      "total": 6
    }
```

**The result I wanted:**

```
"x-movie": [
    {
        "status": 0,
        "total": 33
     },
     {
       "status": 1,
       "total": 2
     },
],
'series': [
    {
        "status": 0,
        "total": 1
     },
     {
       "status": 1,
       "total": 6
     },
]
```

Currently, I have tried many ways, but the result is not as I expected. I'm a nodejs newbie so it's really hard for me. Please anyone give me any comments.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map`:

```
const data = [{
       "status": 0,
       "name": "x-movie",
       "total": 33
    },
    {
      "status": 1,
      "name": "x-movie",
      "total": 2
    },
    {
      "status": 0,
      "name": "series",
      "total": 1
    },
    {
      "status": 1,
      "name": "series",
      "total": 6
    }]

const myMap = new Map()

for (const i of data) {
    if (myMap.has(i["name"])) {
        currentKey = myMap.get(i["name"])
        newKey = [...currentKey, {"status": i["status"], "total": i["total"]}]
        myMap.set(i["name"], newKey)
    } else {
        myMap.set(i["name"], [{"status": i["status"], "total": i["total"]}])
    }
}

console.log(myMap)
```

Output:

```
➜  ~ node test.js
Map(2) {
  'x-movie' => [ { status: 0, total: 33 }, { status: 1, total: 2 } ],
  'series' => [ { status: 0, total: 1 }, { status: 1, total: 6 } ]
}
```

Comment: I just used it the way you suggested. But it returns null : {}

Comment: it's weird! you are iterating on `movie` right? can you maybe update the post and add some logs?